# How to solve this nonlinear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to solve for $A$ is the following equation.

$$
A^{-1} = B + \sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{l=1}^d A_{kl} C^{(kl)}
$$
where

- $A$ is a $d\times d$ positive semi-definite matrix
- $B$ is a $d\times d$ matrix
- $C^{(kl)}$ is a a $d\times d$ matrix; there are $d^2$ different matrices of this form being added together above
- $A_{kl}$ is the entry in $A$ at row $k$ and column $l$

---

What makes this problem hard is the scalar multiplication by elements within $A$.  I've never seen a problem with this property before.  Any ideas on how I might tackle it?